# Using a .jasper file present within a jar file

Tags: java, jar, jasper-reports

We are using `JasperReports` as our reporting tool. Earlier we were using relative paths for
jasper files for filling report and it's working fine.

Now, we want to create a new jar for all compiled `jrxml` files. i.e a jar containing all `.jasper` files for our project.

Is there a way to access those `.jasper` files within a jar file while filling report. Because in documentation, i always see

`fillReport(java.lang.String sourceFileName, java.util.Map params)`

where, sourcefile is always a path on filesystem.

My question is, is there a way to access compiled `.jasper` files present within a jar file
and fill report based on those files ?

**EDIT:**
Essentially what is required is, i need to access `.jasper` files from a jar file, and then fill reports using that `.jasper` file and save the generated reports onto a filesystem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most APIs worth using will provide overloaded methods to accept input streams.  E.G. [`JasperFillManager.fillReport(InputStream, Map)`](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/api/net/sf/jasperreports/engine/JasperFillManager.html#fillReport%28java.io.InputStream,%20java.util.Map%29)

To get in `InputStream`, use `Class.getResourceAsStream()`.